# Twitter request exceed issue

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Twitter request exceed problem. It shows requests exceed 150 per hour.

This is my code :

```
$trends_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends.json?screen_name=".$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['screen_name'];
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trends_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $curlout = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $response = json_decode($curlout, true);
```

I am using PHP curl to get Twitter friend list. If I manuaaly post this URL in browser like `"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends.json?screen_name=Rock_Feather"`.

It works fine, but not giving data back while using curl.

Comment: I'd say it's a server issue. Is CURL or even php-curl installed / enabled on your system? Use `phpinfo();` for this. also check whether curl is allowed to request external urls.

Comment: Err, regarding your error message you receive. Twitter limits requests against a server. Which means, you're allowed to do 150 requests from one single IP per hour. If this machine is used by others, they could also request data from the API which affects your script.

Comment: Thanks, my issue seems to have solved now